# Manually endorse transaction using JAVA Sdk in hyperledger fabric

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am testing a business model where Org1 and Org2 are on a channel. A transaction created by Org1 needs to be endorsed/signed by Org2 after seeing the details. Once transaction is signed by both Org1 and Org2, it gets committed in blockchain.

My guess is that a admin/user in Org2 need to listen to some event on the channel and then add its signature when responding back. I am trying to figure how this can be implemented using JAVA sdk. I am working with chaincode 'fabcar' in following example: https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk

The endorsement policy YAML looks as follows:

```
identities:
    user1: {"role": {"name": "member", "mspId": "Org1MSP"}}
    user2: {"role": {"name": "member", "mspId": "Org2MSP"}}
    admin1: {"role": {"name": "admin", "mspId": "Org1MSP"}}
    admin2: {"role": {"name": "admin", "mspId": "Org2MSP"}}

policy:
    2-of:
      - 1-of:
        - signed-by: "user1"
        - signed-by: "admin1"

      - 1-of:
        - signed-by: "user2"
        - signed-by: "admin2"
```